# Only highlight table rows that are clicked on in React

Tags: reactjs, row, highlight

I currently have a class that renders the output of state data into a table. But I want to be able to highlight rows based on a unique id that each state array has.

Here is the function and render code for the table contents:

```
toggleActive(id) {
this.setState({
  rowIsActive: id,
});
if (rowIsActive === id) {
}
}

render() {
const EventsList = this.props.eventList.map((event) => {
  return scenario.list.map((event) => {
    return (
      <TableRow
        className="tr"
        key={event.id}
        handleClick={() => this.toggleActive(event.id)}
      >
        <Table.Td className="td">{event.name} </Table.Td>
        <Table.Td>
          <div>{event.location}</div>
          <div>{event.numberofpeople}</div>
          <div>{event.host ? event.host : null}</div>
          <div>{event.type ? pickevent.type : null}</div>
          <div>{event.style ? event.style : null}</div>
        </Table.Td>
        <Table.Td>{event.country}</Table.Td>
      </TableRow>
    );
  });
});
return <Fragment>{EventsList}</Fragment>;
  }
}
```

How would I go about implementing this using React or CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example will work if you need to highlight only one row

```
toggleActive(id) {
  this.setState({
     rowIsActive: id,
  });
}

render() {
  const EventsList = this.props.eventList.map((event) => {
    return scenario.list.map((event) => {
      return (
        <TableRow
          className={`tr ${this.state.rowIsActive === event.id ? 'active' : ''}`}
          key={event.id}
          handleClick={() => this.toggleActive(event.id)}
        >
          <Table.Td className="td">{event.name} </Table.Td>
          <Table.Td>
            <div>{event.location}</div>
            <div>{event.numberofpeople}</div>
            <div>{event.host ? event.host : null}</div>
            <div>{event.type ? pickevent.type : null}</div>
            <div>{event.style ? event.style : null}</div>
          </Table.Td>
          <Table.Td>{event.country}</Table.Td>
        </TableRow>
      );
    });
  });

  return <Fragment>{EventsList}</Fragment>;
}
```

Comment: is there anyway for the selected color to have priority over hover colors in the css? because whenever i select and hover over the row the hover color overrides the selected color?

Comment: yep, you can use something like this: ```.tr:not(.active):hover { your_styles_here }``` . [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) you can read more about ```:not``` pseudo class

Answer (score 0):

TableRow should have className based on this.state.rowIsActive.

```
className={`tr${this.state.rowIsActive === event.id ? ‘ active’ : ‘’}`}
```